# Adding css attribute hover using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem when i try to add CSS attributes to this class it gives me an error

My code

```
$('.openerp .nav-pills > li.active a:hover, .openerp .nav-pills > li.active a:focus, .openerp a.list-group-item.active a:hover, .openerp a.list-group-item.active a:focus').css({'color': res["left_hover_font_color"],'background-color': res["left_hover_bg_color"]});
```

error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

Why hover causing a problem here?

Comment: What's `res["left_hover_font_color"]`?

Comment: @j08691 An array. Though I would have made it into an object and call it as `res.left_hover_font_color`, but it's a choice.

Comment: do you have any jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: @ Babydead @j08691 Yep i use dict

Comment: you are using `a:hover` filter in the JQUERY select statement while `a:hover` is not a valid filter

Comment: how i could do so @Sam  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery selectors are similar but not exactly the same as css selectors if you want to target an event such as hover or focus you need to use a callback for example:

```
$('.openerp .nav-pills > li.active a').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'color': res["left_hover_font_color"],'background-color': res["left_hover_bg_color"]});
},function() {
    $(this).css({'color': "",'background-color': ""});
});
```

Comment: I have a problem with that code i don't know why ,,, when i go and select any menu of them and i reselect another on ,,,the first lose the hover and the text disappear

Answer (score 1):

:hover is not a DOM element but a status. The `css()` function of jquery uses `inline-css`. `inline-css` can not be applied to a non-existing element.
If you want to change your `:hover` class's effect, I would using `.addClass()` to add a class such as `alternative-over` and style it with css.

A way to do it with pure jQuery could also be to say:

```
$('a').on("hover", function(){
  $(this).css({your styles});
});
```

A third option is to add css between `<style>` tags in your DOM through jQuery, though I wouldn't recommend it as it gets messy.

**edit: I will try to make an example with your specific code as you've requested, but I'm doing this blindly right now and cannot guarantee it will work right off the bat. A little tweaking might be necessary**

```
//Specify the parents
var obj = $('.openerp .nav-pills > li.active, .openerp .nav-pills > li.active, .openerp a.list-group-item.active, .openerp a.list-group-item.active');

//This makes it grab the "a" within the objects(parents) you've specified before
    $('a', obj).on("hover", function(){
//This is what happens when you enter the area with your mouse
      $(this).css({'color': res["left_hover_font_color"],'background-color': res["left_hover_bg_color"]});
    },
function(){
  //this is what happens when your mouse leaves the area (removes the :hover)
  $(this).attr("style", ""); //resets the inline-styling
});
```

^ The above is a pure jQuery way. I myself would use css to get what you want. Adding and removing the class, like so;

```
//Specify the parents
var obj = $('.openerp .nav-pills > li.active, .openerp .nav-pills > li.active, .openerp a.list-group-item.active, .openerp a.list-group-item.active');

//This makes it grab the "a" within the objects(parents) you've specified before
    $('a', obj).on("hover", function(){
//This is what happens when you enter the area with your mouse
      $(this).addClass("alternative-hover");
    },
function(){
  //this is what happens when your mouse leaves the area (removes the :hover)
            $(this).removeClass("alternative-hover");
});
```

Comment: could you apply what you say to my example or code please for better understanding

Comment: Both doesn't work :( i tried the first one which i would believe it should work but it didn't work

Comment: Could you try and remove the other options from the "var obj"? So, for now, only take 1? `var obj = $('.openerp .nav-pills > li.active');

also, are you getting any (new)  errors? In that case you should let me know, it would make a big difference

Comment: I see now that I had a typo in my code. If you tried to blindly copy-paste it without reading it over, I feel like you're going to hit trouble and keep asking questions. You should try to learn from the answers you get. I'm glad someone elses answer worked for you, but I also predict issues with that one if you don't do anything with the answer.

Good luck, anyway.